# Node JS - Check if JSON File hasOwnProperty with nested elements

Tags: node.js, json, hasownproperty

im simply trying to check if a JSON Object has a specific key.
First i parse the JSON File to an object but when i try this:

```
  console.log("Inspect:" + util.inspect(oldConfig[websiteName][groupName]));
  console.log("Check Prop: " + oldConfig.hasOwnProperty([websiteName][groupName]));
```

my console says this:

```
Inspect:{ tmpTestTitle: { active: false, fileName: 'tmpFilename1' } }
Check Prop: false
```

Im wondering why i can see the key and value by using *util.inspect*, but can't when i try to check with *hasOwnProperty*-function.

I also checked the correct formatting of the JSON-File and tried to reach the key with the dot notations ( websiteName.groupName ).

For supplementation, this is how the whole json-object looks like in the console:

```
{ tmpWebTitle: { tmpGroupname: { tmpTestTitle: [Object] } } }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to check if groupName exists or not ?

Comment: Yes, that's what im trying to and i also want to check some deeper nested keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.hasOwnProperty()` takes string as parameter and checks in the keys of object, not in the keys of nested object.

For your problem you should first access the inner value and check `hasOwnProperty()` on it

```
oldConfig[websiteName].hasOwnProperty(groupName));
```

```js
let oldConfig={ 
              tmpWebTitle: { 
                             tmpGroupname: {
                              tmpTestTitle: [] 
                             } 
                           } 

               };

let websiteName ='tmpWebTitle';
let groupName ='tmpGroupname';
console.log("Check prop:", oldConfig[websiteName].hasOwnProperty(groupName));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot :)